# On the size of a non-empty family of non-empty sets such that every set in the family has a proper subset also in the family

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $ F$ be a non-empty family of non-empty sets such that for every set $A \in F$ , $\exists $ a proper subset $B \subset A$ such that $B \in F$ . I can prove that every set in such a family $F$ is infinite but I'm having trouble to determine whether the family $F$ itself is infinite or not ; I have an intuition that the family must also be infinite but am not able to prove ( or disprove) it ; please help . Thanks

Comment: doesn't a similar method show both at once? or is this a more subtle question about the axiom of choice?

Comment: Maybe answers on http://math.stackexchange.com/q/829188/75923 are useful here.

Comment: @David: drhab's answer uses some choice, Ishfaaq's answer doesn't. What it shows is that for every $n$, there are at least $n$ elements in the collection. In the absence of choice it is consistent that such collection exists where every chain is finite, but the collection itself, of course, cannot be finite.

Comment: @Asaf, thanks for thar helpful clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F$ is non-empty. Then there is a set $A_1 \in F$. Now as per the conditions there is a propoer subset $A_2 \subset A_1$ such that $A_2 \in F$. You can continue to induct that there is a sequence $A_1, A_2, ...A_n, ..$ such that each of them are elements of $F$.

Or proceed by contradiction. Suppose there are but a finite number of elements in $F$. Say, $F = \{B_1, B_2, .., B_n\}$. Now there must be a set $C$ in the finite collection $F$ such that there is no other set in $F$ which is a proper subset of $C$. The absence of such a set $C$ immediately entails that $F$ is infinite. But then since $C$ is in $F$ there must be a proper subset of it which is also in $F$ leading to a contradiction. Hence $F$ must be an infinite collection.

Answer (score 2):

Order $F$ by inclusion. Then it has no minimal element. That makes it possible to construct a infinite chain. So $F$ must be infinite. Start with some $A_1\in F$. Then find $A_2\in F$ as a proper subset of $A_1$. Repeat this.